# jQuery .each not iterating through li

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Have a bunch of li's that are essentially true or false questions. Problem is that it is working for the first li but not the next, next, next etc

jquery code is:

```
<script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            //Run the each iteration 
            jQuery('#question').each(function(i){

                // Hide the initial values 
                jQuery('#true').hide();
                jQuery('#false').hide();

                var answer = '<?php echo the_sub_field( 'true_or_false' ); ?>';     

                console.log(answer);        

                jQuery("#button").click(function($){
                        $.preventDefault();
                        if( answer == 'True' ) {
                            jQuery('#false').hide();
                            jQuery('#true').show();
                        }
                });

                jQuery("#button2").click(function($){
                        $.preventDefault();                 
                        if( answer == 'True' ) {
                            jQuery('#true').hide();
                            jQuery('#false').show();
                        }
                });

            });                 


        });

    </script>
```

html code is:

```
<li id="question">
        <div id="statement">
            <?php the_sub_field( 'question' ); ?>?
        </div>
        <div id="true">
            <?php the_sub_field( 'true_answer' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="false">
            <?php the_sub_field( 'false_answer' ); ?>
        </div>

        <a href="#" id="button">true</a>

        <a href="#" id="button2">false</a>

    </li>
```

I'm getting the right values to check against inside the console - however the each doesn't seem to be doing it for "each".

Thanks in advance :)

Here's the raw output:

```
<ul>


    <li id="question">
        <div id="question">
            George likes to sing?
        </div>
        <div id="true">
            You are correct, even when it's out of tune         </div>
        <div id="false">
            Sadly we wish it was false, but it's true           </div>

        <a href="#" id="button">true</a>

        <a href="#" id="button2">false</a>

    </li>

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            //Run the each iteration 
            jQuery('#question').each(function(i){

                // Hide the initial values 
                jQuery('#true').hide();
                jQuery('#false').hide();

                var answer = 'True';        

                console.log(answer);        

                jQuery("#button").click(function($){
                        $.preventDefault();
                        if( answer == 'True' ) {
                            jQuery('#false').hide();
                            jQuery('#true').show();
                        }
                });

                jQuery("#button2").click(function($){
                        $.preventDefault();                 
                        if( answer == 'True' ) {
                            jQuery('#true').hide();
                            jQuery('#false').show();
                        }
                });

            });                 


        });

    </script>   


    <li id="question">
        <div id="question">
            Aj likes to say the word "WoWoWoWomp"??
        </div>
        <div id="true">
            You are right, almost twenty times a day            </div>
        <div id="false">
            Unfortunately you were wowowo wrong :)          </div>

        <a href="#" id="button">true</a>

        <a href="#" id="button2">false</a>

    </li>

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            //Run the each iteration 
            jQuery('#question').each(function(i){

                // Hide the initial values 
                jQuery('#true').hide();
                jQuery('#false').hide();

                var answer = 'False';       

                console.log(answer);        

                jQuery("#button").click(function($){
                        $.preventDefault();
                        if( answer == 'True' ) {
                            jQuery('#false').hide();
                            jQuery('#true').show();
                        }
                });

                jQuery("#button2").click(function($){
                        $.preventDefault();                 
                        if( answer == 'True' ) {
                            jQuery('#true').hide();
                            jQuery('#false').show();
                        }
                });

            });                 


        });

    </script>   


</ul>
```

Comment: You've posted one `<li>` in your question. I also see no element with the ID mythbuster to match `#mythbuster`. Post the rendered HTML as the PHP seems irrelevant here.

Comment: jQuery('#mythbuster').each is already wrong. IDS have to be unique

Comment: IDs should be unique. You should switch to using classes for elements like this that are created inside a loop.

Comment: sorry - adapted it slightly for stackoverflow - it will be question as the id

Comment: ***ALL*** id's must be unique in a page @jamper. You're better off , in this case, using classes and modifying your jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to iterate. Replacing the `id` with `class` and rewriting the jquery shortens the code greatly. Here is the HTML output -

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="question">George likes to sing?</div>
        <div class="true">You are correct, even when it's out of tune</div>
        <div class="false">Sadly we wish it was false, but it's true</div> <a href="#" class="button">true</a>
 <a href="#" class="button2">false</a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="question">Aj likes to say the word "WoWoWoWomp"??</div>
        <div class="true">You are right, almost twenty times a day</div>
        <div class="false">Unfortunately you were wowowo wrong :)</div> <a href="#" class="button">true</a>
 <a href="#" class="button2">false</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Given that you can use this jQuery, which only needs to appear one time, not multiple times as you have done above. One set of functions handles *all* of the questions / answers. -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // hide the answers    
    jQuery('.true, .false').hide();

    // show answer based on click
    jQuery('.button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.true').show();
        jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.false').hide();
    });
    jQuery('.button2').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.false').show();
        jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.true').hide();
    });

});
```

You're also running an unnecessary test to see if a variable is set because the variable, being set as it is, is always set, so this has been removed from the code.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/svxkpzfo/).

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming this `<li>` is the pattern for all.

Given this: `id` is only allowed to be used **one time** ... either:

1. Change the id for each type (i.e. id="Question1", id="Question2"), or
2. Use classes (i.e. class="Question") which will allow for selecting multiple elements at one time.

While I referenced `id="Question"` above, this pattern should remain true.  An `id` **must** be unique; this applies for: question, statement, true, false, button, button2, and any other id's you have listed.

Comment: It also looks like the OP might have some other id's which are duplicated, like `question, statement, true, false, button` and `button 2`.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to use a class for iterating through items. Id should only be used once (for accessing a unique element). See the following example.

Jquery Code.

```
$('div#questions ul li.answer').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Html.

```
<div id="questions">
<ul>
    <li class="answer">True</li>
    <li class="answer">True</li>
    <li class="answer">False</li>
    <li class="answer">False</li>
    <li class="answer">True</li>
</ul>
</div>
```